# Oracle MERGE won't insert only update

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to insert/update values from a webform into my oracle database.

This is my query

```
MERGE INTO myTable myTarget 
USING (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = 0) mySource
     ON (mySource.ID = myTarget.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
    LOC_ID = 1,
    AUTHOR = 'Lee'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
        LOC_ID, 
        AUTHOR
    )
    VALUES (
        1, 
        'lee'
    )
```

For some reason only the UPDATE works.

So if I have a record with `ID = 0` then the values get updated but if I don't have a record with `ID = 0` the values do not get inserted. `0 rows merged.` Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how merges work. The source query (your `select * from mytable where id = 0`) is what is used to determine what data to update or insert.

If you don't have any records in mytable where the id = 0, you don't have anything to insert or update with.

I think what you had in mind was something like:

```
merge into mytable tgt
using (select 0 id, 1 loc_id, 'Lee' author from dual) src
  on (tgt.id = src.id)
when matched then
  update set tgt.loc_id = src.loc_id,
             tgt.author = src.author
when not matched then
insert (tgt.id, tgt.loc_id, tgt.author)
values (src.id, src.loc_id, src.author);
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't appreciate the need to create a sudo table using DUAL. Thanks

Comment: it's the source table/subquery that needs to hold the records to be updated/inserted. If your source records aren't already in another table, then you need to create them using the dual table (if you had more than one row, you'd use a union all, eg. `select 0 id, 1 loc_id, 'Lee' author from dual union all select 1 id, 2 loc_id, 'King' author from dual union all ....`. Bear in mind that in the update part of the merge statement, you can include an additional where clause to further filter the rows being updated.

Comment: @Boneist Crisp Explanation. It solved my problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The main culprit here is your joining condition. Suppose you have two rows having IDs 1 and 2 respectively. So in this case the joining condition itself will fail.
Case 2 we have 0 and 1 respectively as ID, now here only ID = 0 will qualify and straightaway the Update statement will be executed. So in any case you won't be able to insert a new row to your table . You have to use either a PseudoTable or another work table to insert a new row.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you say:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = 0`

you only grab all records with `ID = 0`

You should delete the `where` clause to get all the other records from the table.

Comment: If I do that, then it doesn't restrict the merge to just one row and updates all the rows with my values

Comment: Ahh okay now I understand. Seems like Boneist got the better answer here.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your input